# $|x|^p/p^p\le e^{-x}+e^{x}$ for all $p$ positive and $x\in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I wish to prove the following inequality

$$|x|^p/p^p\le e^{-x}+e^{x}$$

for all $p$ positive and $x\in \mathbb R$.

My partial progress:

Taking the $p$-th root and $\log$, it suffices to show

$$f(x):=(1/p)\log(e^{-x}+e^{x})- \log (|x|/p)$$

is non-negative. But I have trouble in analyzing the derivative and minimal value of this function. Maybe there is some other trick to approach this? Maybe we should consider this as a two-variable problem?

Comment: Scince both numbers can change you should consider this a 2 variable problem.

Comment: Wlog take $x > 0$. Then $x/p < e^{x/p} \implies (x/p)^p < e^x$ by the positivity of $p$. Since $e^{-x}>0,$ we can add it to the upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x\ge0$ wlog. We maximize the LHS w.r.t. $p$ by log differentiating:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dp}p\ln(x/p)=\ln(x/p)-1=0\Leftrightarrow p=x/e\Leftrightarrow x=pe$$

It is easy to observe this is a relative maximum, as the second derivative gives:

$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dp^2}p\ln(x/p)=-\frac1p<0$$

Substituting it in, we see it suffices to check

$$(x/p)^p\le e^{-x/e}\le e^x+e^{-x}$$

which can be done by moving everything to one side and verifying the derivative is positive.

Comment: Thanks! But I guess the zero to the equation in the first line should be $x=pe$?

Comment: Ah yes my bad. Thanks for the catch.